# How to prevent GitHub's rebase and merge from creating new commit hashes

Tags: git, github

I have a `dev` branch that I've been committing work to over the course of several months. When I got the application to a place I was happy with for an initial release, I cut off a new branch from `dev` called `prod` and deployed it separately as a production release. I've since added more work to the `dev` branch, and want to merge those changes into `prod` so that the `prod` commit history is perfectly mirrored to `dev`. I was under the impression that I could do this using GitHub's Rebase and Merge option when creating a pull request for `dev` into `prod`, with my understanding being that git would write each of the 5 new commits exactly from `dev` directly onto the `prod` branch. However what instead happened was each commit was added to `prod` with a new commit hash compared to what it was assigned on `dev`, so now my `prod` branch is "5 commits ahead, 5 commits behind `dev`". I want the commits from `dev` to be reflected exactly on `prod`, including the commit hashes, so that when I ship new changes from `dev` to `prod`, `prod`'s status is always "This branch is up to date with `dev`". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just point `prod` to the commit referenced by `dev`?

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen: [_"...rebasing achieves this by re-writing the commit history on the base branch with new commits. ... Rebase and merge on GitHub will always update the committer information and create new commit SHAs"_](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github#rebasing-and-merging-your-commits)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the link - still wrapping my head around the intricacies of git. How should I be handling shipping changes to my prod branch to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Hashes mean something. I don't understand why you think you can just change them. In this context it means that they point to something in a content-addressable filesystem (the Git repository).

Answer (score 1):

> I want [that] when I ship new changes from dev to prod, prod's status is always "This branch is up to date with dev".

Stop wanting that.

> What am I doing wrong?

Wanting that.

The only way two branches can ever be exactly up to date with one another is if they are *the same branch* (i.e. the two branch names point to the very same commit). But the only way that could ever happen would be if

(1) they really *are* effectively the same branch, as in the case of your local `main` and your remote-tracking `origin/main`, or

(2) you have just performed a fast-forward merge of one branch into the other, which on a remote server that uses pull requests is impossible. I mean, you could say *locally* `git switch prod; git merge --ff-only dev` and it might work, in which case they would be up to date with each other; but you could not push that, because it would violate the rule that merges should pass thru a pull request.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! Should I understand then that it's not uncommon for production branches to have mismatched commit history compared to their dev counterparts? Just trying to confirm general best practices here.

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as "mismatched". If you merge into a branch, you get a merge commit that one branch has but the other does not. If you squash onto a branch, you get a squash commit that one branch has but the other does not. If you "rebase merge" onto a branch, you get _copies_ of the commits from one branch appearing in the other branch, and so _both_ have commits that the other does not. This is not an "intricacy" or a "mismatch", it's simply what Git is. It seems like you don't know what Git is, or what a merge is? Try my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

Comment: One "best practice" is not to have two separate branches at all. We, for example, have `main` only. When we are ready for a release, we _tag_ that commit and keep working. However, there are many, many other ways of working; none is "best".